# Google cloud functions not executing Stripe call

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I am running a series of stripe charges in promise structure.  When I run just a single execution of a charge everything works fine.  But when I try to run more than one the stripe charge line of code simply won't execute.

Does anyone have insight into my code structure or google cloud functions that would prevent the execution of several stripe calls from occurring?

```
const idempotency_key = randomstring.generate();  // prevent duplicate charges

    const amount = total + 30;
    const currency = "usd";

    console.log("Blue Scarfs", idempotency_key);
    console.log("Blue Scarfs", user_ID);

    return docRef2.doc(`/users_stripe/${user_ID}`).get()
            .then(snapshot => {

            console.log("the dollars", snapshot);
            console.log("the dollars", user_ID);
            const customer = snapshot.data().id;
            const charge = {amount, currency, customer};
            console.log("Bills", charge);
            return stripe.charges.create(charge , { idempotency_key });
            console.log("Bills");
            })
```

Comment: I would assume that your google cloud function is configured to run for too short of a timespan.

Comment: Where can I edit that?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec
gcloud functions deploy FUNCTION_NAME --timeout=TIMEOUT FLAGS...

Comment: also try using async await: async () => {
const snapshot = await docRef2.doc(`/users_stripe/${user_ID}`).get()
const customer = snapshot.data().id;
            const charge = {amount, currency, customer};
            console.log("Bills", charge);
            return stripe.charges.create(charge , { idempotency_key });
            console.log("Bills");
            })

Comment: I'm changing the time and nothing is changing about the execution at all.  I don't think its the time because it runs fine for one or two charges on the 60s interval.  Plus I'm not getting anytime out errors.

Comment: ok so convert to async/await and use console.time() then console.timeEnd() (or just start): and then another one one after your second request is called. like:
`const time = Date.now()` then after the first API request console.log(Date.now() - time) and after await of the second API request log that again.

Comment: Great answer! Could you please put this as an answer instead of a comment so that the community can upvote and possibly be accepted as an answer?